# How to configure ULS Viewer for SharePoint 2013 to view the Event Log?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, uls, logs

I have downloaded ULS viewer, But i am unable to view the event, do i need to configure something to view the Event log?

Comment: the SharePoint ULS Viewer doesn’t read the Event Viewer Log, it only read the SharePoint Trace Log, for more details check [SHAREPOINT ULS VIEWER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/15/uls-viewer-tool/)

Answer (score 3):

ULS viewer is for ULS logs, not system Event log. 
So you need to open log file (default location is `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS`) or connect to current log stream which is possible only if you run ULS Viewer from SharePoint server.

Comment: Can add that I always open default location pressing Ctrl+U

Answer (score 3):

As Others mentioned, ULS viewer provides a simplified view of ULS log files in SharePoint 2013 that supports aggregation, filtering, sorting, highlighting, append, and more.

But you cannot check / hook the event logs in it. If you want to live monitoring of your farm( as they have farm option in it, means multiple servers at same time). then you have to configure it that way.
[image]

Honestly, it is really hard to view / hard understand the logs, in live stream.I configured it for live stream and i am done after loosing alot of hairs.

[ULS Viewing Like a Boss](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/08/22/uls-viewing-like-a-boss-uls-viewer-is-now-available.aspx)

There are other monitoring Tools which will capture the event log i.e MSFT own product SCOM which we are using.